# Addeventlistener not returning button value

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to code a simple rock paper scissors game and want to use "addeventlistener" to return the value of the buttons but im am not how and further i can't seem to console.log it to print what i want either.

[code for my rock paper scissors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCzuK.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: the element firing the event will be `window.event.target` but I'm afraid you won't get any better answer if you don't first better craft your question to include that code shown in picture as text

Comment: Shouldn't `hi` be within quotes - `"hi"`?

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` accepts only string parameters. What you're trying to provide is variable hi but it is not defined.
so either you can do:

```
var hi = 'hello'
console.log(hi)
```

or you can do
`console.log('hi')`

For reference, visit [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp)